# Raycast problems with Hololens 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I have an application with MRTK in Unity 2019.4.9 for Hololens 2 where I need to raycast from the camera to the spatial mesh to create an instance of an object.

The following method returns a RaycastHit with the point of collision with the mesh and requires as parameter the coordinates in **VIEWPORT** (values between 0 and 1).

(0, 0) = Bottom left corner.

(1, 1) = Upper right corner.

Following this method the objects appear correctly when I give the coordinate (0.5, 0.5). But when I move away from the center, the objects appear farther and farther away from the point of collision.

Objects tend to be placed towards the center.
For example if I want to place to the right, it appears displaced to the left, the same logic occurs in each direction. The closer to the edges of the screen, the worse the precision.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?
I am using ViewportPointToRay.

```
private bool GetWorldPoint(Vector2 p, out RaycastHit hit)
{
    hit = default;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(p);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit h, Mathf.Infinity, spatialLayer))
    {
        hit = h;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you get the viewport values you pass in as parameters?

Comment: The position is obtained from another application telematically. A teleassistant sees what the Hololens user sees on his screen. If the assistant clicks on his screen, the coordinates are collected in values between 0 and 1 and sent to the Hololens to launch a raycast and place an object where the assistant has marked.

Comment: Concretely it is to do: Input.MousePosition.x / Screen.width. And the same on the vertical axis.

Comment: Why not rather use the mouse position and ScreenPointToRay directly?

Comment: Because the width and height of each screen is different. For example, the coordinate (0.5, 0.5) on a 1920x1080 screen is (960, 540) in pixels while on a 1280x720 screen it is (640, 360).

Comment: I know what it means .. but if you actually originally get the value in screen pixel space then why not simply use that as said in [`ScreenPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html)?

Comment: As I said before, the width and height of each screen is different. If there is a 500x500 screen and I click on the top right of the screen and get the coordinates (500, 500) and pass those coordinates to a 1000x1000 screen, it will place the object in the middle of the screen. Instead, I want it to place it at the top right, in the same place it was clicked on the first screen.

Comment: By the way, I tried multiplying the viewport value by the hololens screen width and height and using ScreenPointToRay but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using MRTK I would suggest you to read more about [pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/pointers?view=mrtkunity-2021-05), they provide you with an unified API to obtain the world intersection point for each type of pointer, see [Pointer Result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/pointers?view=mrtkunity-2021-05#pointer-result)